# Add database for Linq-to-SQL

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, linq-to-sql

I am attempting to add a database to a Visual Studio 2010 VB.Net Windows Forms project to interrogate it with Linq-to-SQL. I have added the Linq-to-SQL Entities to the project.

I can connect to the required database with SQL Server Manager using the Server Name, and SQL Server credentials. But using the Add Database feature in Visual Studio requires me to know the database file name, which I don't.

Is there any way to specify the new database using the server name and credentials in Visual Studio 2010, or alternatively to find out what the file name is from SQL Server Manager, or is there a tutorial anywhere I should be following, in case I am doing the whole thing completely wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file name will be the database name with a mdf extenstion. You can find this out in Management Studio by selecting the db and right click Properties and then click the files tab. last column will have the file name.

Comment: I did wonder why the filename didn't appear on that screen. But I also didn't notice the horizontal scroll bar...